# Call a Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(), which is within a user form from another module?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, userform

I have been trying to call a Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(), which is behind the user form LoadQuoteDetails2, from a different module using the line of code below:

```
Sub Automation()    
    Application.Run "LoadQuoteDetails2.CommandButton1_Click"    
End Sub
```

However, it throws me the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>      Cannot run the macro `LoadQuoteDetails2.CommandButton1_Click`. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all the macros may be disabled.

However, I am sure that the macro is present within the workbook. Does anyone know the reason why might this be happening?

If not this, is there a different way to call a private sub behind a user form from a different module?

Note that I do not want to change the user form or the code behind it in any way; for e.g. making it as public or adding a public module behind the user form which calls the private module etc.

Comment: The only way I know is `LoadQuoteDetails2.CommandButton1.value = true`

Comment: IMO calling control event code in a userform from within another module is a sign of poor design.